# What is the alternative to the Resource Owner Password Credentials grant type?

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, rest

I have my REST API server which stores user data and handles all the requests. The front-end lives on another server and then there's also a mobile app. I would like to integrate OAuth2 but have my doubts on what grant type to choose. On one hand, the ROPC grant type is best in my situation since I don't allow any third party apps, and I don't want user to be redirected anywhere and the user never gets to use my endpoints directly, only with some kind of interface (front-end, or mobile GUI). So, what are the possible options here?

Answer (score 1):

Normally Authorization-Code Grant is the way to go. I assume you are asking this question, because you heard that ROPC is rather unsafe to use and should be avoided when possible? And that would be true.
Use Authorization Code Grant. Better: use Authorization Code Grant with PKCE. (PKCE is mandatory on mobile Apps and a good practice on WebApps too)
I know that the Authorization Code can seem complicated at first, but it is really the way to go with OAuth.

[Okta Blog to PKCE](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/08/22/okta-authjs-pkce)